# Why the image of quadratic Veronese map has the form $v\cdot v$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

It says that the image of quadratic Veronese map  $v_2(P^1)$ is the subset of $P(Sym^2V)$ with the form $v\cdot v$.

Isn't it has the form $x^2+xy+y^2$? So how can it be some $v\cdot v$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work with a basis $e_1, e_2$ for your two dimensional vector space $V$ such that $\mathbb{P}^1 = \mathbb{P}(V)$.  Then the Veronese map $\mathbb{P}(V) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\text{Sym}^2 V)$ is indeed given by sending $[v]$ to $[v \cdot v]$, but this can be understood more concretely using coordinates.  A natural basis for $\text{Sym}^2 V$ is $e_1^2, 2 e_1 \cdot e_2, e_2^2$.  Thus a vector $v = x e_1 + y e_2$ maps to $v \cdot v = (x e_1 + y e_2)^2 = x^2 e_1^2 + xy 2e_1 \cdot e_2 + y^2 e_2^2$, or in homogeneous coordinates $(x : y) \mapsto (x^2 : xy : y^2)$.

(The reason for including $2 e_1 \cdot e_2$ instead of $e_1 \cdot e_2$ in the basis for $\text{Sym}^2 V$ is to keep the map in homogeneous coordinates from having any non-unital coefficients.)

Answer (score 2):

The $2$-uple Veronese embedding maps $(x_0:x_1)\in\mathbb P^1$ to $(x_0^2,x_0x_1,x_1^2)$ in $\mathbb P^2$.
So the image satisfies the equation $y_1^2=y_0y_2$.

Comment: I am sorry I did not state the right question at the very first. I have stated the it again.

Comment: @Akatsuki I cannot understand your question. For me the 2-uple Veronese map indeed maps $\mathbb P^1$ to a conic curve. What's meaning of "with the form $v\cdot v$"?

Comment: Since $P(Sym^2 V)$ is equivalent to $P^2$, so it make sense.

Comment: @Akatsuki Could you explain the meaning of this dot action in projective plane?

Comment: Dot just means multiplication. Since $SymV$ is an algebra, the multiplication makes sense.